# restrict jtextfield to accept only numbers?

Tags: java, swing

What can I do to make the "sueldo, salud, AFP" textfields to accept only numbers?

```
    private void sueldoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

}                                      

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String sueldo = this.sueldo.getText();
    int sueldoInt = Integer.parseInt(sueldo);
    String salud = this.salud.getText();
    int saludInt = Integer.parseInt(salud);
    String afp = this.afp.getText();
    int afpInt = Integer.parseInt(afp);
    String otros = this.otros.getText();
    int otrosInt = Integer.parseInt(otros);

    double saludD = sueldoInt * (saludInt * 0.01);
    double afpD = sueldoInt * (afpInt * 0.01);

    int calcular = (int) (sueldoInt - saludD - afpD - otrosInt);

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,+calcular);
```

Comment: Use a JFormattedTextField or JSpinner for post validation, use a DocumentFilter for real time validation

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *`JFormattedTextField`* with a *`MaskFormatter`*:

```
MaskFormatter formatter= new MaskFormatter("########");
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```